# why doesnt javascript provide a method to get ip address

Tags: javascript

It looks like javascript does not provide the ability to get the ip address.

Though we can get the ip address using server side scripting.

Is this done based on security?

Comment: What would you do with the IP address from javascript? BTW: if the server supports SSI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) chances are there's the REMOTE_ADDR variable (google it).

Comment: Server address something like window.location

Comment: Sort of. Not much use is it, seeing as it's on the other side of the firewall...

Comment: ChristopheD: thanks for the comment, i was just trying to understand the reason why it is not a part of javascript

Comment: Why do you want it? It's not really that useful.

Comment: 100,000,000 all on 192.168.1.1, yeah that's useful

Answer (score 5):

Not to be obtuse but - *because the language designers did not think it was necessary*.

There is a huge amount of typically "essential" functionality which is missing from JavaScript (think about the filesystem, networking, I/O, multithreading, etc).  This is because the JavaScript language was designed as a web-browser scripting language, not a general purpose programming language (although recent runtimes have filled the gaps).

It's not difficult to determine the client or server IP address (e.g. it would be trivial to write an "nslookup" AJAX service on your server) and there are likely not many security concerns in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

‌Because IP address has meaning only in the context of a connection between a client and a server over Internet, while JavaScript is purely a client-side language, designed to work regardless of a connection or a host.

Comment: don't tell the node.js brigade that it's only a client side language :)

Comment: :-D Well, in Node.js you are not doing traditional, orthodox JavaScript, are you? And I think this question was about that.

Comment: More and more the notion of "traditional, orthodox JavaScript" needs to encompass server-side uses of the language.

Comment: I agree, but then it would not be 'traditional'. I think a revise (and a big one) or maybe another version of the language should be made available.